# Is it possible to add service-worker.js to existing react app, if yes, how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Studying Progressive Web App using reactjs and I know that to create a **new** app there is a decent way to do that for making a new app using the below:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

Then, I read through the docs of crate-react-app and I know service-worker.js is opt-in due to adding difficulties to debuug...but at this point, I am wondering are there any ways to add the service-worker.js afterwards/to existing react app that do not contain it.

I am also curious whether I could create a new app, grab that service-worker.js file and then plug to any other react apps.
In addition, is there any further configuration is needed in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: r u using create-react-app ?

Comment: sure, but I have an react app that has been created before without using the pwa template, so that it doesn;t have the service-worker.js inside

Comment: aha got it  let me post my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if existing app has been create by create-react-app
you can simply add service-worker.js file beside index.js
because cra(create-react-app) by default searching for service-worker.js to add that to build directory
and in index.js you can register your service-worker in this way :

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Register a service worker hosted at the root of the
  // site using the default scope.
  navigator.serviceWorker.register(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`).then(
    registration => {
      console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration);
    },
    /*catch*/ error => {
      console.error(`Service worker registration failed: ${error}`);
    }
  );
} else {
  console.error('Service workers are not supported.');
}
```

Comment: So, that means the default service worker can be copied, plug and play in other react app too?

Comment: Yes,if other app is created using create-react-app